# Hot Link To A Specific Cell Comment In Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a way to create a comment for cell D7 (for example) such that when the user hovers over it the comment has a *hot link* or *hyperlink* to cell A100?  I dont know what else to call it other than a hot link or hyperlink, however its not like the hyperlink we know of in HTML.  Or, maybe it could it be?

The effect that is desired is that when the user sees that comment, he/she can click on the link to cell A100 if they choose to do so.  I do not wish to create a macro or use VBA behind a button, etc..  It must be within the comment box itself.

One of the issues I have run into is that once you move the mouse, the comment goes away.  The comment might be able to be displayed all the time if it needs to be for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Comments can only have text. You cannot even hover on a comment box. Comment boxes are only visible as long as you hover on the related cell. This is intentionally done by design. I don't know if you can change this behavior using a macro or addon, but this can be a feature request for the future releases of Excel.

Comment: I was hoping for a different answer but perhaps I shall make a feature request.  I'll have to devise a workaround for the client.  Thanks for the response!